# Can I use DVD+R to install an OS? (as opposed to DVD-R)

Tags: boot, iso-image, dvd-burning, windows-10-preview

I've been trying (since I have a pack of 100 DVD+Rs) to burn Windows 10 to one and install it on my laptop. However, whenever I try, it just boots as normal and doesn't consider the DVD ROM a boot device. Previously I used a DVD-R to install Windows 8.

I have the order set in the BIOS to be `Disc > Hard Drive > Network`, but it still doesn't recognize it. I’m using the official “Technical Preview ISO,” and burning it with the Windows 8.1 built-in disc burner (right-click ISO, burn disc image).

**Does this mean it’s impossible to use a DVD+R (rather than a DVD-R) as an install disc for an OS?** Is this instead an issue with the Windows 10 ISO? I tried again with Ubuntu on a disc from the same pack, but it, too, was ignored.

Comment: It *should* work. Do you get any BIOS prompt when booting, like "Press any key to boot from CD"? You can check your download is not corrupt by using some SHA-1 calculating utility and comparing to the appropriate value on [windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-iso](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-iso).

Comment: @JakeGould I am specifically talking about DVD+R instead of DVD-R

Comment: @AndrewMorton no, it goes straight form BIOS into Windows. I tried spamming F-keys, too, but to no avail. I thought it was a bad download, so I re-downloaded it, but got the same results. I'll try that hashing method.

Comment: @JakeGould That'd be a great answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that **DVD+RW** is more reliable than DVD+R.

I wasted 7 DVD+Rs trying to burn ISOs of Windows 7, 8.1, and 10. But, when I burned the same ISO OS files onto DVD+RW, they became bootable!

This is because DVD+RW's Cartridge Configuration is different than DVD+R's.

If you can't buy DVD+RW then buy DVD+pro!
No need to change the setting on the ISO file to make bootable; burn it into DVD+RW or DVD+pro and it will become bootable.

Comment: Note that RW media is designed to be used in an  "RW" drive.

Answer (score 3):

DVD+R or DVD-R or anything else. It doesn't matter. That stuff is all just media. How it is partitioned, formatted & burned is what matters. That's why you can download an ISO and just “burn” it to anything: CD-R, DVD-R, DVD+R, USB Flash, SD, Hard Drive… Whatever. It’s all
just media to put data on and read.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should be able to use a bootable DVD ISO image to make a bootable DVD.

In your specific case of installing Windows 10 onto a PC running 8.1, you should be able to simply right click and mount the image, and run the setup from there.

Comment: Wouldn't it unmount when the computer has to do its several restarts for installation?

Comment: It would, but by that point it's got everything it needs (that's how I installed it on my test machine)

Comment: Thank you, I'll test this method! I upvoted to counteract that downvote :3